# How does Jake travel back to the present in 11.22.63?

Tags: stephen-king, 11-22-63

In the pilot episode of 11.22.63, Jake is shown that he can travel back to 1960 by walking in the closet in the diner. Before he takes on the task of preventing JFK's assassination, he comes and goes a couple of times. All of the times he visits the past by walking in the closet, but it isn't shown how he gets back to the present.

I haven't read the book, so I do not know if it is explained there, but **do we know how he gets back to the present?**

Comment: Wouldn't he just come out of the closet? I would think that would be easier to do now than in the 1960s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jake has to go back to the town when he first arrived 1960 and *step up* to the closet step. He could feel that step with his feet (even though it's invisible in 1960) so he knows where the "door" is.

This is probably why he fell the first time he tried the portal (when Al made him try the closet, he fell down).

Comment: They do elaborate on it in the books, including a scary episode the second time he returns where he doesn't find the steps where he expects them, and starts making plans to stay in 1960 until he hears Al's voice.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I was avoiding the book but... ಠ_ಠ